# How do i compile something with Pgocaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, camlp4

I'm trying to use [Pgocaml](http://pgocaml.forge.ocamlcore.org/) for database interactions within my application.

This is the file I'm trying to compile:

```
let () =
  let dbh = PGOCaml.connect () in
  let insert name salary email =
     PGSQL(dbh) "insert into employees (name, salary, email) values ($name, $salary, $?email)"
  in
  insert "Ann" 10_000_l None;
  insert "Bob" 45_000_l None;
  insert "Jim" 20_000_l None;
  insert "Mary" 30_000_l (Some "mary@example.com");

  let print_row (id, name, salary, email) =
    let email = match email with Some email -> email | None -> "    -"      
    in Printf.printf "%ld %S %ld %S\n" id name salary email in

  let rows =
    PGSQL(dbh) "select id, name, salary, email from employees"
  in List.iter print_row rows;

  PGOCaml.close dbh
```

This is how I am trying to compile it:

```
  ocamlbuild  -use-ocamlfind -pkg pgocaml pgex.native
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -package pgocaml -modules pgex.ml > pgex.ml.depends
File "pgex.ml", line 4, characters 19-97:
Error: Syntax error
Command exited with code 2.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PG'OCaml is a syntax extension, it is not a regular ocaml code, so you need to take extra steps to let it perform its magic. First, read the [tutorial](http://pgocaml.forge.ocamlcore.org/pgoctut.pdf) which also explains how to compile projects with pgocaml. Second, tell the build system that `pgex.ml` should be preprocessed with `camlp4` - i.e. create `_tags` file with the contents `<pgex.ml>: syntax(camlp4o)`.

Comment: Sorry for the time between replies. I am trying to follow the makefile inside of the link in the pdf you provided, and I am getting the following error while trying to "make" it. makefile:8: warning: overriding commands for target `pgex'
makefile:6: warning: ignoring old commands for target `pgex'
make: Circular pgex <- pgex dependency dropped.
make: *** No rule to make target `.ml', needed by `pgex'.  Stop.

Comment: Although this did not directly answer my question, it put me on the right path. I do believe the make portion of the pdf provided above is a little convoluted (it did not work for me any way). I just rewrote it in a shell script and I was able to get it to compile after a little tinkering.